# How many squares can standard chess pieces control?

Tags: chess

How many squares can you control with only one set of chess pieces of the same color? (8 Pawns, 2 Knights, 2 Bishops, 2 Rook, Queen and King)

Edit: Pieces cannot attack (control) the square they are currently occupied.

Comment: Does a piece count the space it is on as controlling?

Comment: No. Other pieces must control that square

Comment: All of them, the pawns can reach the other side and become queens!

Comment: there's a chess se you know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is *relatively* easy and that many combinations will exist. This seems to be an example of such a position:

[image]

To answer the question, the set of pieces for one side can attack *all* squares (and then some).

Comment: There are pieces there that aren't even needed.

Comment: Yep, but the question seemed to imply that it wants them all used. _In fact_, getting them _all_ on there was the tricky part (pawns tend to push things around undesirably and don't bring much to the party - they block other pieces and only attack 2 squares!!)

Comment: Yes, true, I made another question that deals with least pieces needed! Feel free to answer that one.