# How Many Pieces from Both Sides can you Place on a Chess Board Without Attacking a Side?

Tags: chess

How many pieces can you organize on a Chess board without one side being attacked by the other? This scoring will be used to prove you have the highest.

**Piece cost:**

- Pawn - 1
- Knight - 3
- Bishop - 3
- Rook - 5
- Queen - 9

**Rules:**

- Both sides must have the same pieces on the board
- Your score is totalled by only 1 side
- One color cannot attack the other
- No king allowed.

Comment: Is there restriction on the number of pieces of each type that can be used?  If not, the eight queens should be the baseline, scoring 36.

Comment: There is no restriction on pieces.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the bottom up:

Three rows of 8 black queens
One row of black pawns
One row of white pawns
Three rows of white queens

224.

Because the black pawns attack down and the white pawns attack up, they can be placed next to each other without attacking each other.

[image: 224 Points]

Comment: Can you provide a picture?

Comment: [Here you go.](http://www.apronus.com/chess/stilldiagram.php?d=AqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqppppppppPPPPPPPPQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ0&w=8&h=8)

Comment: The pawns attack eachother in your answer.

Comment: @warspyking white moves up the board, so the black pawns are behind them meaning they can't attack

Comment: Oh... I guess that makes sense.

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/how-many-chess-pieces-are-needed-to-control-every-square-on-the-board

Comment: that is not right, they should be in front of each other, this is a kind of loophole

Comment: @Elgert Even if you invert the colours, removing one line of queens in favour for one empty row between the pawns still gives a pretty maximal solution - and the principle of the solution is unchanged.

Comment: @oerkelens there is a better solution than leaving a empty row between the pawns

Answer (score 8):

Although I like my first answer, I did also wonder how good I could manage with black and white in their normal positions. The best I've gotten so far uses 16 queens, 4 rooks, 4 bishops and 4 pawns.

180.

[image: 180 Points]

Comment: I believe you can change `D6 -> black pawn`, `E3 -> white rook`, `E4 -> white pawn` to gain 3 points

Comment: @Joe Both sides must have same pieces. White would have 1 more rook than black.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the same-pieces argument. How very dull.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Without it, I'm pretty sure I could manage 576.

Comment: @Joel You know the white side can have black pieces right?

Comment: @warspyking Yes, but I haven't come up with a way to do that and get a higher score than 180 (you know, excluding my 224)

Comment: Then again that'd be pretty hard to do anything with.