# How many Chess Pieces are needed to control every square on the board? No Piece Restriction

Tags: chess, optimization

You may use as many pieces as you like. Pieces do not control the square they occupy.

Accepted Answer goes to the person that has the least score.

Piece cost:

- Pawn - 1
- Knight - 3
- Bishop - 3
- Rook - 5
- Queen - 9

**Note1**: The king has no score, it was implied that it is not allowed.

**Note2**: I meant to imply only 1 colour was allowed.

Yes this is [How many Chess Pieces are needed to control every square on the board?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/how-many-chess-pieces-are-needed-to-control-every-square-on-the-board?noredirect=1#comment7788_2872) without the set restriction.

Comment: Come on people, let's beat 30!

Comment: Do you use any software to find the attack paths or is it manual hard work :)

Comment: @skv manual is better I think.. otherwise what's the fun

Comment: @d'alar'cop agree 100%

Comment: @d'alar'cop: But a tool that can help us visualize the attacked squares will be helpful for us to find better solution, unless you want to restrict yourself with unnecessary restriction. It's like comparing mental arithmetics with pencil-and-paper-assisted calculation. =D

Comment: @justhalf BUT, when you play real chess you don't have any assistance (of scratch paper or anything). so these _can_ be useful at honing the important chess skill of instinctively knowing where's safe etc... although we might gain new insight from visualisations... all ways have their argument I suppose. do what makes you happy :)

Comment: @d'alar'cop: I see. I would rather rephrase "all ways have their argument" as "It depends on the personal aim of doing the challenge", since it seems that you're concerned with "honing the important chess skill", while I personally only concerned with the best solution for this challenge (I played chess long long time ago! haha). Thanks for clearing things up! =)

Comment: @MarkAdler Your solution does not cover 3-8 and 6-8. http://www.apronus.com/chess/stilldiagram.php?d=A__k__k___________________BP__PB__BBBBBB_________________________0

Comment: Shame that we can't use fairy chess pieces. Then, all that is required is a leviathan and a pawn covering it. (Note: leviathan is a piece able to move anywhere on the board; used as handicap piece most oft.)

Comment: @CoNoR I'd give that piece a cost of inf

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here's a solution that only takes 28 points:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the new front runner. I always thought that the solution should have a few pawns - they are the cheapest way to paint in spaces not otherwise covered.

Comment: and I had a feeling that the best solution somehow had to be symmetrical, just a feeling though but feels complete now

Comment: I can't answer because I only just signed up and the post is protected (can we change that?), but a modification of this solution that costs only 26 is to move bishops from d4 to c5 and from e4 to f5.  Those bishops are then attacking b4 and g4, so the pawns at a3 and h3 can be eliminated, dropping the cost by 2 to 26.

Comment: @Tim Doesn't work - then the bishops in the center would be unprotected.  It is impossible to improve on this solution by just moving pieces around - I think it might be possible to do so by adding a knight, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Mmm, you're right, I missed that.

Comment: I confirm that 28 is optimal.

Comment: @RobPratt What method did you use to confirm it?

Comment: @Brilliand I used integer linear programming.

Comment: Rob here is an expert in ILP. He always used ILP in any puzzles in Puzzling, lol

Answer (score 20):

Can this be considered an improvement over justhalf's solution or am I missing something here total comes to 29

[image]

Comment: +1, can't see a flaw (well, except all pieces should be either black or white, but a white rook won't break your solution :)

Comment: excellent good job. do you reckon we can beat this?

Comment: Thanks, I think so, I am sure @justhalf, the original thinker can, I just tinkered with it

Comment: Best answer so far, it's marked as Accepted Answer till someone beats 29, someone such as @d'alar'cop

Comment: I have one with a cost of 27 but the site won't let me post it since I just signed up.

Comment: @user You need a reputation for that? Are you sure?

Comment: @warspyking The question is protected and can't be answered by anyone with lower than 10 rep, which has to have been earned on this site (the +100 you get if you're an established user on another SE site doesn't count).

Comment: @user1943369 I suggest flagging the question and asking for it to be unprotected so you can post your answer.

Comment: @user1943369 10 rep is pretty easy to get.  Not entirely trivial, granted, but you have a pretty good chance of getting rep on another question more quickly than a moderator would get around to unprotecting this.

Comment: @warspyking: There seems to be an answer with score 28 now =D

Comment: @user1943369: Hmm, yeah, I just realized that [association bonus does not count.](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user). Perhaps you want to answer other question first? Then we can upvote you so you can answer here =D

Comment: @user1943369 I have discovered a truly marvellous solution requiring just 26 points, which this margin is too narrow to contain.

Comment: Best answer has been switched to @Brill 's answer

Comment: @Nicholas Haha, awesome reference.

Comment: @Nich Then please, do post.

Answer (score 12):

This does not qualify as the lowest score, but it does answer the question of

> How many Chess Pieces are needed to control every square on the board?

[image]

It takes 5 pieces

Comment: scores 45 (= 5x9)

Comment: It is actually possible with 4 queens and a bishop, hence a score of 39.

Comment: @Evargalo I'd be interested to know where you would put them. Are you taking into account "Pieces do not control the square they occupy" with your solution?

Comment: @Warlord099 : alas, no, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 10):

I found some other solutions which cost $30$. I'm posting this in the hope someone else can improve any of these.

[image: Cost-30-attack-all-squares]

[image: Cost-30-attack-all-squares-2]

Comment: Are the pawns required in _either_ of those solutions? Should be 28 if occupying a square is considered "controlling" it.

Comment: @CrimsonChris: But occupying is _not_ considered controlling, as clearly stated in the first line of the question :)

Answer (score 8):

I have a solution that costs 30. It is actually from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_chess_problem#Domination_problems):

[image]

Comment: d'alar'cop If you enjoy Chess puzzles here's another one based on Knight's tour: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2929/the-bunnys-tour

Answer (score 5):

I have another solution at 28 points - can't see an easy way to get lower, though.

[image: zerris]

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but here's a solution that costs 26:

[image]

Comment: Some of the pieces are blocking each other.

Comment: Yes, the point on the rook is to control every square the bishops are on, but it really only controls the top bishop;  the ones below that are blocked since the rook cannot directly attack them since the top bishop is in the way.  The question wasn't clear, however, so I think this is a really good answer!

Comment: Ah yes. I hang my head in shame