# Chessboard Domination - Adjusted Piece Values

Tags: chess

No restriction on number of pieces of each type, but all pieces must be the same color. Pieces do not control the square they occupy.

The pieces on the chessboard must, through their combined efforts, control every square on the board. Accepted Answer goes to the answer with the lowest score.

Piece cost:

- Pawn - 1
- Knight - 2
- Bishop - 3
- King - 3
- Rook - 4
- Queen - 6

This is a modified version of [How many Chess Pieces are needed to control every square on the board? No Piece Restriction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2907/how-many-chess-pieces-are-needed-to-control-every-square-on-the-board-no-piece), and the piece costs were chosen based on the difficulty of using them in that challenge.

Comment: I seem to be accumulating downvotes.  I suppose that's because of this: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1321/a-flood-of-chess-puzzles - Well, at least now I know what I'm being downvoted for.

Comment: I think too much too soon, and with unnatural (not the rules of chess) makes it a little uninteresting

Comment: @skv I get that. My main aim was actually to find fair values for the various pieces within the rules of chessboard domination, but this is the closest I could get and still have a question with a clear accept condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Forgot about the Queen]

I wanted to try to make use of the kings, and this is what I got. It ends up at a score of 23.

Edit: Bah, forgot the queen's square. Now up to 25 (couldn't use a pawn since then a king isn't covered).