# The Universe's Secret

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction, no-computers, sudoku

To find the universe's secret, first solve the Sudoku variant with #s 1-7 only.

No number may be repeated on any diagonal. No numbers go in the squares with red or green dots.

Then use the solution and the red/green squares to find the universe's secret.

The accepted answer will show detail and be well-articulated.

[image: All Diagonal Sudoku Variant 1-7]

<sub>I'm feeling generous. The accepted answer will receive 500 bonus rep points.</sub>

Comment: Ahh, I see what's happening. But I won't be able to finish the puzzle, so I'll leave this to the other solvers out there.

Comment: ^ By what's happening I mean that I think that I have solved the first bit...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following from @justhalf and @Jafe’s answers,

> We now have the 9x9 sudoku solved using the numbers 1-7, and can now look at the black, unfilled squares. Sum up the values of the digits orthogonally adjacent to each black box, and add/subtract the number of dots lit up, depending on whether they are colored green/red, respectively. Convert to letters (using A1Z26) and read them in reading order to get the answer: **THE LAW OF ATTRACTION**.

Comment: 200 pts coming your way

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer. I have the answer to the sudoku but still stuck on the dot puzzle.

Sudoku solution

> The 6 only has one possible place it can go in the top-left box. After that, there's only one spot for a 6 on the seventh row. Every 6 is placed pretty quickly based on that.
>
>  [image: Partially solved sudoku grid. Sixes placed.]
>
>  Putting a 5 in row 1 column 4 would make it impossible to put a 5 anywhere in the top-left box. So the 5 can't be there, leaving only one other place it can go. That forces the 5 in the top-left box.
>
>  [image: Partially solved sudoku grid. Sixes and some fives placed.]
>
>  The 5 in the bottom-right box must be in column 9, which means the 5 in the mid-right box must be in column 8. Only one place where it fits. From there it's simple to place the rest of the 5's.
>
>  [image: Partially solved sudoku grid. Sixes and fives placed.]
>
>  Only one place where a 2 goes in the bottom-right box now. That gives us the 2 in the central box, which in turn forces the 2 into place in column 2. After that there's only one option for the 2 in the top-left box, and it's straightforward to fill in the remaining 2's.
>
>  [image: Partially solved sudoku grid. Sixes, fives and twos placed.]
>
>  The 1 only has one possible place on row 2 now. That allows us to place the 1 in the bottom-middle box. The remaining 1's are easily placed.
>
>  [image: Partially solved sudoku grid. Sixes, fives, twos and ones placed.]
>
>  The 4 has only one option on row 3. That fixes the 4 in the bottom-right box, and lets us fill in the rest of the 4's.
>
>  [image: Partially solved sudoku grid. Sixes, fives, twos, ones and fours placed.]
>
>  Many ways to fill in the 3's from here, and put a 7 into all the remaining boxes. This is the finished sudoku grid.
>
>  [image: Solved sudoku grid]

Green/red dots (stuck on this, probably a dead end)

> Each box represents a number between 1 and 16. Reds are negative and greens are positive. This could indicate movement through the alphabet to form a message. (You can always reach any letter with a movement of either +1...+16 or -1...-16, assuming it wraps around on both sides.) I'm not getting any meaningful message as a result, though, so this might be a dead end...

Comment: Looks fantastic so far

Comment: Extraction: rot13(Nqq hc gur qvtvgf begubtbanyyl nqwnprag gb rnpu oynpx obk, naq nqq/fhogenpg gur ahzore bs qbgf yvg hc, qrcraqvat ba vs gurl ner pbyberq terra/erq, erfcrpgviryl. Pbaireg gb yrggref naq ernq va ernqvat beqre gb trg gur nafjre: GUR YNJ BS NGGENPGVBA.)

Comment: @SeptaCube Ooh, that must be it. You should post that as an answer!

Comment: 200 pts coming your way

Answer (score 5):

(partial answer) First, the sudoku (the following is more like my solving process, so some steps may be out of order):

> Each 3x3 box has 7 cells, so each box should have all numbers 1-7.

Step 1:

> [image]
>  I filled the center with possible numbers
>  Then noticed that 6 can only go at the cells highlighted red in the respective box. This means R7C2 is the only place for 6 in that box.

Step 2:

> [image]
>  Notice that R6C7 can't be 6 since the two possibilities of 6 in center box exclude this cell. So 6 can only go on the cells highlighted red on the right box. This means R1C7 is the only place for 6 in top right box.
>  Then we can fill the rest of the 6.
>  [image]

Step 3:

> [image]
>  Top box can only have the red cells for 5. So R2C3 is the only place for 5 in that box. Which also gives us R1C6. And based on possibilities of 5 on bottom right box, we can also deduce R5C8 as 5. Then R8C4, R7C1, R4C2, and finally R9C9.
>  [image]

Step 4:

> [image]
>  We can fill 2 in bottom right box now. Then R5C5. Then top left and top center boxes can only have 2 at R1 and R3. So top right box must have 2 at R2, which would be at R2C9. Then fill up the rest of the 2.

Step 5:

> [image]
>  Left center box can only have R5 as 1. So R6C8 is 1, and we can fill up the rest of 1.

Step 6:

> [image]
>  Top left and top center can only have R1 and R3 as 3. So top right must be R2C7. Then fill up the rest of the 3.

Step 7:

> Then we can fill up the rest of the 4 and 7 easily. To arrive at this final sudoku part:
>  [image]

Now moving on to the red/green part. Since it seems like the formation of the dots have no meaning individually, let's replace it with the count for visualization.

> [image]

Comment: In Box 7, how did you immediately get the 6 resolved?

Comment: Box 8 must have the 6 at R9, Box 1 must have the 6 at C1. Together with existing 6, Box 7 can only have the 6 at R7C2. I admit I didn't notice that Box 1 has only one possible place for 6 like you did.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot the diagonals. My solvng process was a bit different, so that's why I was asking.

Comment: Huh? I am the one forgetting the diagonals, lol. You remembered the diagonal and so could deduce that Box 1 has only R3C1 for 6.

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes sometimes, so it's fine.

Comment: Looks great so far. Now for the last step...

Comment: @Stevo oh, I just realized you're not the other answerer, lol. I saw your comment in the question about getting the first part, and saw partial answer, I assumed it was you.

Comment: 200 pts coming your way

Comment: @JLee whoa thanks. But how could one give 200 to three answers? I thought bounty needs to increase each time.

Comment: For any one question it does, so I will award you a bounty for [another question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2907/how-many-chess-pieces-are-needed-to-control-every-square-on-the-board-no-piece) you answered.